# Out of memory when use for loop to input parameter in recursive function Python

Tags: python, recursion, out-of-memory, tail-recursion

I have a recursive function:

```
def recursive_func(parameter1):
   .....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_parameter_input = [a,b,c,d,e]
    for item in list_parameter_input:
        recursive_func(item)
```

**Note**: my `recursive_func` is very complex but I'm sure it won't have any error.

**The problem is** when I input a `parameter1` with a single item in `list_parameter_input`, it's fast and needs small memory. When I input a `parameter1` using for loop, it's prolonged and makes `out of memory`.It's so weird.

I'm checked time when `recursive_func` complete with each value in `list_parameter_input`.

When input with not using `for loop`: `recursive_func(a)` need `x` time.

When input with using `for loop`: `recursive_func(a)` need more `x` time (`10x`,`11x`,...) but with `b,c,d,e` give a same time.

I don't know why it's happen but I'm really sure `recursive_func(a)` is very fast when I input `a` with not using `for loop`

Comment: in `recursive_func(i)` what is `i`? it is undefined

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]; you're describing code and providing isolated snippets, but the actual function is needed to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: @Nullman, I updated my post, please check again

Comment: Have you tried running profilers and memory checking programs on it? I mean the for loop doesn't do something different than passing the values themselves. So either it's about a weird data type due to the loop (unlikely) or it's a particular value for which the recursion just takes longer.

Comment: @haxor789, the weird is different time complete when I use and don't use `loop` to pass a parameter

Comment: I tried to monitor memory with `Task manager` and calculate time complete and it like I said above

Comment: I was thinking more about something like these: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html which show you what functions are being called.

Answer (score 0):

I mean `recursive_func(i)` is probably `recursive_func(item)` as you're never using i anywhere.

But the real problem seems to be that you're running the entire loop for each recursion. So each element of the list starts a recursion where it loops through the entire list, not just the rest of the list but the entire list. And each of the element of that loop does the same so:

`5` recursions for the elements in the list

`5*5` recursions for the elements in the list in the recursions

`5*5*5` recursions for the elements in the list in the recursions of the recursion
...

That soon leads to a stack overflow.

Comment: The problem is when I pass directly like this: `recursive_func(a)`, it was completed very fast. But when I use `for loop` to pass a parameter, it's very slow and out of memory so I don't think it's not a problem about  stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your description of the code (you are technically not providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but if the code looks like this:

```py
def recursive_func(parameter1):

    ...

    list_parameter_input = [a,b,c,d,e]
    for item in list_parameter_input:
        recursive_func(item)
```

... then you have an infinite loop.

I.e. Unless the `list_parameter_input` is modified (items are removed) you are not making progress.

Can you verify that you are actually making progress through the input parameters?

Comment: I use `for loop` to pass a parameter to `def recursive_func`. It's mean `for loop` out of `def recursive_func`

Comment: Then I think you need to provide more info about the recursive function. What does it do? You haven't provided a minimal reproducible example yet :)

Comment: My recursive function is very complex, let's me think about how to provide a minimal reproducible example.
But I'm sure when I run with pass a parameter not use `loop` it's very fast, I don't think error from my `def recursive_func`